# Pull stock value of last business day of a month

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, time-series

Need help in Pulling stock value of last business day of a month in a time series/dataframe
I am executing the fol code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
start = datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 31)
end = datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 30)
stocks = ['AAPL', 'GOOG']
col = 'Adj Close'
df = web.get_data_yahoo(stocks,start,end)
data = df.ix[col]    
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This gives me a dataframe with all the close values.
I want to get the values only from the last business day of the month

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore the question, I've managed to find the answer